# Yii Migrations with multiple databases - specify DB?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, yii, database-migration

We have a huge app built on Yii.

So far migrating was done by copy-pasting SQL dumps in phpliteadmin/phpmyadmin, but that's not very convenient.

I want to use `CDbMigration`s for it, with `yiic migrate`.

The issue is that we have two databases - a small sqlite one for config and settings, and large mysql for storing some historical records.

How do I specify what database the migration belongs to?

This is the basic migration structure, for illustration.

```
class do_stuff extends CDbMigration
{
    public function up()
    {
        // create table
    }

    public function down()
    {
        // drop table
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `config.php` file, specify your database connections in the `components` array.

```
    'db1'=>array(
                'class'=>'CDbConnection',
                'connectionString' => 'mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=localhost;dbname=dbname1',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'root',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
            ),
    'db2'=>array(
                'class'=>'CDbConnection',
                'connectionString' => 'mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=localhost;dbname=dbname2',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'root',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
            ),
```

Then in your migration, you can do the following:

```
protected $dbConnection1;
protected function getDbConnection1()
{
    if (null !== $this->dbConnection1) {
        return $this->dbConnection1;
    }

    return $this->dbConnection1 = Yii::app()->getComponent('db1');
}
```

Repeat for your second connection.

Then use those methods to get the CDbConnection for each database, from which you can create commands to execute.

Comment: thanks, will accept when I get to actually try it out. Busy with other work challenges, no time for new stuff :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CDbMigration::setDbConnection()` to change the default, or override the `getDbConnection()` method. This is similar to another proposed solution, but it had a typo and it needed to be a public function, so I include here the fix.

In your migration, include the following (change `db1` for the defined connection name in your configuration files):

```
protected $dbConnection1;
public function getDbConnection()
{
   if (null !== $this->dbConnection1) {
      return $this->dbConnection1;
   }

   return $this->dbConnection1 = Yii::app()->getComponent('db1');
}
```